# Would parts connecting to GPIO be on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know this is a stupid question, but I have a raspberry pi (computer) and a minecraft server (computer). According to the help center, electronic items that interface/operate with a computer are on-topic. Would it also be on topic to ask for something that will connect to a GPIO pin on the raspberry pi which then completes the circuit so the minecraft server turns on or is that better to ask on electronics SE?

Comment: If you flipped the question around and asked "What can I use to remotely turn on/off a server?" then I think it would be on topic. Of course a Raspberry Pi with GPIO would be a valid answer, but other solutions exist. Asking about the RPi specifically using GPIO to connect to the server has precluded any chance to recommend an alternative to the RPi and then the question is very focused and not asking for a hardware recommendation.